# Stack Overflow with GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-overflow

this code generates a stack overflow error when this method is run on a threaded runnable. Also, if you have any suggestions on efficiency, feel free to let me know! You may be wondering if some parts are necessary but most are. Thanks for any help!

```
private void solveBrute(long start, long end) {

    long current = start;
    boolean found = false;
    boolean first = true;
    String check = "";
    while(!found && current <= end && !shouldStop) {
        check = this.intToBaseN(current, MainHS.getInstance().possiblechars);
        logVerbose("Trying " + check + " : " + getMd5Digest(check));
        if(first) {
            //MainHS.getInstance().central.logVerbose("Thread " + threadnum + " is starting value " + current + ". (" + last + ")");
            first = false;
        }
        if (valid(MainHS.getInstance().solveFor, check)) { 
            MainHS.getInstance().found(check, getMd5Digest(check));
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        current++;
    }
    if(!found && !shouldStop) {
        solveBrute((long)start + (long)(MainHS.getInstance().possiblechars.length) + 1L,(long)end + (long)(MainHS.getInstance().possiblechars.length) + 1L);
    }
}
//This is how I launch each thread
for(int a = 0; a < solvers.size(); a++) {
        final Solver s = solvers.get(a);
        final long sv = startingvalue;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                s.solve(wordlistSplit[current - 1], current + start - 1, f, l,sv,sv + possiblechars.length / MainHS.getInstance().possiblethreads);
            }
        });
        threads.add(t);
        t.start();
        current++;
        startingvalue += (possiblechars.length / MainHS.getInstance().possiblethreads) + 1 /*possiblethreads - 1*/;
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long)100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The error produced is as follows (the lines are off by 106):

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessControlContext.optimize(AccessControlContext.java:388)
at java.security.AccessController.getContext(AccessController.java:502)
at java.awt.AWTEvent.<init>(AWTEvent.java:106)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.<init>(InvocationEvent.java:224)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.<init>(InvocationEvent.java:188)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.<init>(InvocationEvent.java:150)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.scheduleProcessingRunnable(RepaintManager.java:1384)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.scheduleProcessingRunnable(RepaintManager.java:1377)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.addDirtyRegion0(RepaintManager.java:434)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(RepaintManager.java:456)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4795)
at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3286)
at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateChildren(WrappedPlainView.java:292)
at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.removeUpdate(WrappedPlainView.java:485)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.removeUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1616)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.removeUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1876)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireRemoveUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:260)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleRemove(AbstractDocument.java:623)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.remove(AbstractDocument.java:591)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:667)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1718)
at me.jadengrossman.hashsolver.gui.Solver$1.run(Solver.java:168)
```

However, the code below works just fine. I want the first code to work, how can i do this?

```
public void solveBrute(final int aaa, String first, String last) {
    count = 0;
    lettercount = aaa;
    START_OF_SEARCH_AREA = first.toCharArray()[0];
    END_OF_SEARCH_AREA = last.toCharArray()[0];
    progress.setMaximum(1000000000);
    possiblevalues = (int)Math.pow((int)END_OF_SEARCH_AREA - (int)START_OF_SEARCH_AREA + 1, aaa);
    progress.setValue(0);
    progress.setVisible(true);
    progress.setStringPainted(true);
    boolean pro = false;
    for(Component c: MainHS.getInstance().central.statsBox.getComponents()) {
        if(c.equals(progress)) {
            pro = true;
        }
    }
    if(!pro) {
        MainHS.getInstance().central.statsBox.add(progress);
    }
        FIRST_CANDIDATE = "";
        boolean found = false;
           for(int b = 0; b < aaa; b++) {
               FIRST_CANDIDATE += "" + first;
           }
           String c = FIRST_CANDIDATE;
            while ((c = next(c)) != null && !shouldStop) {
                if (valid(MainHS.getInstance().solveFor, c)) {
                    MainHS.getInstance().found(c, getMd5Digest(c));
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(aaa != c.length()) {
                    MainHS.getInstance().central.logVerbose("Finished " + (c.length() - 1) + " words. Found " + count + "/" + this.possiblevalues);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found && !shouldStop && MainHS.end >= aaa + MainHS.getInstance().possiblethreads)
                solveBrute(aaa + MainHS.getInstance().possiblethreads, first, last);
}
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Well, that's a mess of non-contextual code...want to point out where `me.jadengrossman.hashsolver.gui.Solver$1.run(Solver.java:168)` might be. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Looks like you are solving something via brute force. Well, depending on the problem instance, you'd normally expect such algorithms to stack overflow. Implement some pruning or some clever memory management.

Comment: A lot of times, a stack overflow indicates that your recursive algorithm doesn't have the appropriate stop conditions or it otherwise descends too deep into the recursion. If the code at the bottom works and the code at the top doesn't, I'd look at the if() right above the solveBrute recursive call.

Comment: @skytreader See I don't think so, as I said, the second method works just fine (I have had it run up to 10 hours with no issues). My theory is that I am overloading the JTextArea, and could fix this by making a "queue", however I doubt it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer That part isn't relevant for the code. However, the line that causes the error is when I call the method again recursively... Interesting. thanks for the input!

Comment: Based on the stack trace, it is, cause it's the only none library method call in the stack trace...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ill take your word for it. Edited! And thank you!